# Replacing elements of a list that depend on elements of other lists

Tags: string, replace, wolfram-mathematica, list-manipulation

I have two lists:

data1 = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}

data2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

I want to replace the elements in data2 depending on the value of data1.

For example, if data1=0, i want data2 to replaced with 0, otherwise i want data2 to stay as it is.

The output i am looking for is:

data2 = {1, 0, 0, 4, 5};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the required output, if `data1 = 0`, `data2` is *not* replaced with 0.

```
data1 = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0};
data2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

data2 = MapThread[If[#1 == 0, #2, 0] &, {data1, data2}]
```

> {1, 0, 0, 4, 5}

also

```
data2 = UnitStep[-Abs@data1]*data2
```

> {1, 0, 0, 4, 5}

Answer (score 0):

another way..

```
ReplacePart[data2, Position[data1, 0] -> 0]
```

> {0, 2, 3, 0, 0}

note your example output doesn't agree with the text of your question.